# How to use member function in functional in a container

Tags: c++, functional-programming, variadic-templates

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   void funcOne(int a, float b);
   void funcTwo(std::string);
   void funcThree();
};
```

I would like to create a container that holds pointers to member functions.

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::function< void(/*FUNCTION ARGS*/)>> myMap;
```

As each member function is different with different number or args and types of args. I reckon there would be some way to specify the function using variadic template... could someone please let me know the definitions needed at the place of the comment `/*FUNCTION ARGS*/`

Comment: `As each member function is different with different number or args and types of args` So what now? These types conflict with each other. How do _you want_ them to be represented?

Comment: Imagine you've done this, and you have `myMap[0](`args here`)`. How do you know how many, and what type, of parameters, to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Each function has a different type. You can use an `union`, or better `std::variant` to represent different types.

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::variant<
     std::function<void(MyClass&, int, float)>,
     std::function<void(MyClass&, std::string)>,
     std::function<void(MyClass&)>
>> myMap;
```

> could someone please let me know the definitions needed at the place of the comment /*FUNCTION ARGS*/

`std::function` has magic to convert `void (MyClass::*)(FUNCTION ARGS)` into `void (MyClass&, FUNCTION ARGS)` or `void (MyClass*, FUNCTION ARGS)`. So just add `MyClass*` or `MyClass&`.